# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc not rendering @scripts section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

All seems to be setup correctly and rending of the @section scripts works in some places but not others. NOTE: this in not a partial view. It's a main view where its not working.

**Views/_ViewStart.cshtml**  specifies the layout

```
@{​​​​​​​​
    Layout = "_Layout";
}​​​​​​​​
```

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml** which you can see gets pulled in cause the pages are displayed with header and footer. In that there is various html and the code

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

The within a UserController it returns a view like

**return View("CreateOrEdit", model);**

which has an equivalent Views/User/CreateOrEdit.cshtml

The following code does not get the users.js rendered.

```
@section Scripts
{​​​​​​​​
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/users/users.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
 within scripts
}​​​​​​​​
```

**To get the the user create edit screen via UserController**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModel mode) {
  ...
  return View("CreateOrEdit", model);
}
```

*(Oddly enough with my application other views that include @section scripts work correctly.
when you land on an Index.html page and not a named page via return View(model);)*

Comment: What's your project structure? I can load the script locally.

Comment: For your view CreateOrEdit.cshtml, try adding this at the top:
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Thanks @Filipe for the suggestion. Unfortunately I have tried that but you then get a double view situation as the layout has already been specified in Views/_ViewStart.cshtml